# Convert connect address with address familiy AF_SYSTEM to human readable string

Tags: macos, kernel, dtrace

### Background

I'm writing some `dtrace` program which tracks application socket file descriptors. Aim is to provide logs which help me spot leak of file descriptors in some very complex OS X application.

[Here is my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47159408/1387438) with [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373124/1387438).

### Problem

I want that my program is logging address to which file descriptor has been connected to. In examples there is a code which partial do what I need: `soconnect_mac.d`, here is [link to github](https://github.com/jorgev/dtrace-scripts/blob/master/soconnect_mac.d).

`soconnect_mac.d` works great when applied on Firefox, but it completely fails in case of my application. Quick investigation shown that `soconnect_mac.d` is able to interpret only `AF_INET` (value 2) family address and som library used by my application is using `AF_SYSTEM` (value 32) family address.

I can't find anything which could help me convert received address to something what is human readable.

So far I've got this:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

inline int af_inet   = 2 ;  /* AF_INET   defined in Kernel/sys/socket.h */
inline int af_inet6  = 30;  /* AF_INET6  defined in Kernel/sys/socket.h */
inline int af_system = 32;  /* AF_SYSTEM defined in Kernel/sys/socket.h */

… // some stuff

syscall::connect:entry
/pid == $target && isOpened[pid, arg0] == 1/
{
    /* assume this is sockaddr_in until we can examine family */
    this->s = (struct sockaddr_in *)copyin(arg1, arg2);
    this->f = this->s->sin_family;
    self->fileDescriptor = arg0;
}

/* this section is copied with pride from "soconnect_mac.d" */
syscall::connect:entry
/this->f == af_inet/
{
    /* Convert port to host byte order without ntohs() being available. */
    self->port = (this->s->sin_port & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    self->port |= (this->s->sin_port & 0xFF) << 8;

    /*
     * Convert an IPv4 address into a dotted quad decimal string.
     * Until the inet_ntoa() functions are available from DTrace, this is
     * converted using the existing strjoin() and lltostr().  It's done in
     * two parts to avoid exhausting DTrace registers in one line of code.
     */
    this->a = (uint8_t *)&this->s->sin_addr;
    this->addr1 = strjoin(lltostr(this->a[0] + 0ULL),
                          strjoin(".",
                                  strjoin(lltostr(this->a[1] + 0ULL),
                                          ".")));

    this->addr2 = strjoin(lltostr(this->a[2] + 0ULL),
                          strjoin(".",
                                  lltostr(this->a[3] + 0ULL)));

    self->address = strjoin(this->addr1, this->addr2);
}

/* this section is my */
syscall::connect:entry
/this->f == af_system/
{
    /* TODO: Problem how to handle AF_SYSTEM address family */

    /* Convert port to host byte order without ntohs() being available. */
    self->port = (this->s->sin_port & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    self->port |= (this->s->sin_port & 0xFF) << 8; // this also doen't work as it should

    self->address = "system family address needed here";
}

// a fallback
syscall::connect:entry
/this->f && this->f != af_inet && this->f != af_system/
{
    /* Convert port to host byte order without ntohs() being available. */
    self->port = (this->s->sin_port & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    self->port |= (this->s->sin_port & 0xFF) << 8;

    self->address = strjoin("Can't handle family: ", lltostr(this->f));
}

syscall::connect:return
/self->fileDescriptor/
{
    this->errstr = err[errno] != NULL ? err[errno] : lltostr(errno);
    printf("%Y.%03d FD:%d Status:%s Address:%s Port:%d",
           walltimestamp, walltimestamp % 1000000000 / 1000000,
           self->fileDescriptor, this->errstr, self->address, self->port);

    self->fileDescriptor = 0;
    self->address = 0;
    self->port = 0;
}
```

What is even more annoying my code has failed to read port number (I get 512 value instead one of this: 443, 8443, 5061).
IMO problem is first `syscall::connect:entry` where it is assumed that second argument can be treated as `struct sockaddr_in`. I'm guessing `struct sockaddr_storage` should be used in case of `AF_SYSTEM` address family, but I didn't found any documentation or source code which proves this in direct way.

My section with `this->f == af_system` condition properly catches events from application I'm investigating.

Comment: If the address family isn't `AF_INET`, then the structure copied into `this->s` isn't a `struct sockaddr_in`.  For example, if the address family is `AF_INET6`, the structure is a `struct sockaddr_in6`.  If it's `AF_UNIX`, the structure would be `struct sockaddr_un`.

Comment: I'm aware, but I assumed that first two fields are always same and I can at least fetch port number, I had to use some struct. Question is what structure should be for `AF_SYSTEM`?

Comment: *Question is what structure should be for `AF_SYSTEM`?  That should be a `struct sockaddr_ctl`.  There isn't a port number in that.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/kern_control.h?language=objc

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I will gladly accept it.